# Unicode-Math Bold Math Font Not Correct

Tags: fonts, bold, unicode-math, boldmath

I am wondering what I am doing wrong. I am using LuaLaTeX and trying to load the kpfonts. I understand the math version of this font supports bold math. But when I use `symbf` I don't get the expected result. A comparison of the bold versus regular math versions is shown below. The bold looks upright/regular. I don't know why, it doesn't quite look right. Or is my intuition wrong here? Am I specifying bold incorrectly?

Note when I compile this I do get the warning `Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted`. Might this mean the bold math is actually missing and some type of upright substitute gets put in its place?

[image: bold-comp]

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont[Path=fonts/serif/]{KpRoman}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]
\setsansfont[Path=fonts/sans_serif/]{KpSans}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]

\setmathfont[Path=fonts/math/]{KpMath-Regular}[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = KpMath-Bold,
]

\begin{document}

\[
    \phi = \int f(x) x dx
\]

\[
    \symbf{\phi = \int f(x) x dx}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: symbf (like mathbf) is upright bold. use symbfit (around each character)

Comment: but symxx uses the same font to use the bold font use `\boldmath` before the equation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

`\symbf` is upright bold, you can use `\symbfit` for bold math italic, but both use characters from the Unicode math alphabets in the regular font.

As with classic latex, to access the bold math font use `\boldmath` before the equation. It appears the bold font is not a full math font and misses the bold math characters.

I removed the `[Path=f` options as they stop the example working if the fonts are installed in the usual texlive locations.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{KpRoman}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]
\setsansfont{KpSans}[
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular,
    BoldFont = *-Bold,
    ItalicFont = *-Italic,
    BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic
]

\setmathfont{KpMath-Regular}[
    Extension = .otf,
    BoldFont = KpMath-Bold,
]

\begin{document}

\[
    \phi = \int f(x) x\, dx
\]

\[
    \symbfit{\phi} = \int \symbfit{f}(\symbfit{x}) \symbfit{x}\, \symbfit{d}\symbfit{x}
\]

\boldmath

\[
    \phi = \int f(x) x\, dx
\]

\[
    \symbfit{\phi} = \int \symbfit{f}(\symbfit{x}) \symbfit{x}\, \symbfit{d}\symbfit{x}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: what is expected in the last equation? my understanding is that the letters should be in something like ultrabold, and that's right, these ultrabold glyphs are not provided by KpMath-Bold.otf. Am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielFlipo yes, or if designing ultrabold is too much, having the same bold alphabet as the regular font so you get something rather than nothing would be good I think.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll add the regular (bold and bold italic) glyphs the next version. I do not think that having ultrabold is worth the pain.

Comment: @DanielFlipo thanks